# How do I get a richlistbox with a fixed listhead?

Tags: firefox-addon, cross-platform, xul

Targeting Firefox 29+, I'm trying to create a `richlistbox` with a `listhead`, containing `listheader`s, that should stay fixed at the top if the `richlistbox` content is scrollable, with:

```
<richlistbox width="400" height="315" seltype="multiple">
  <listhead>
    <listheader label="level" pack="end" width="90"/>
    <listheader label="marker" pack="center" width="115"/>
    <listheader label="default" pack="center" width="90"/>
    <listheader label="prime" pack="center" width="105"/>
  </listhead>
  <richlistitem>
    <!-- some rich content -->
  </richlistitem>
  <!-- enough identical richlistitems here to make them scrollable -->
</richlistbox>
```

However, it does not work as expected: the `listhead` scrolls along with the `richlistitem`s, in stead of staying fixed-positioned.

I've tried adjusting the `listhead` element and/or replace `listheader` elements with `treecol` elements (as suggested [here](http://mike.kaply.com/2011/08/05/richlistbox-tricks-for-your-add-on/) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=118312)), but that didn't do anything for me.

Currently the best working solution I have come up with myself is by styling it with:

```
richlistbox {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
richlistbox listhead {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

However, although this gives acceptable results on Ubuntu, it doesn't on Mac (width of `listhead` is too small (about 5px) and there's too much space (about 3px) between it and the scrollable content), and, although I don't have access to a Windows computer right now, I suspect it will give an alternative result there as well.

Any suggestions to make this work, less hackish, cross-platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this guy right here: http://mike.kaply.com/2011/08/05/richlistbox-tricks-for-your-add-on/

You have to do something like this:

```
  <listheader style="border: 0; padding: 0; -moz-appearance: none;">
    <treecol value="First Header" label="level" pack="end" width="90"/>
    <treecol value="Second Header" label="marker" pack="center" width="115"/>
    <treecol value="Third Header" label="default" pack="center" width="90"/>
    <treecol value="Fourth Header" label="prime" pack="center" width="105"/>
  </listheader>
```

so that makes your code above like this: you can copy paste this code at http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/xuledit/xuledit.xul but you have to download the addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-xul-manager/?src=ss which whitelists xul urls, and then add this url. then just copy paste this on the site:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

<richlistbox width="400" height="315" seltype="multiple">
  <listheader style="border: 0; padding: 0; -moz-appearance: none;">
    <treecol value="First Header" label="level" pack="end" width="90"/>
    <treecol value="Second Header" label="marker" pack="center" width="115"/>
    <treecol value="Third Header" label="default" pack="center" width="90"/>
    <treecol value="Fourth Header" label="prime" pack="center" width="105"/>
  </listheader>
<richlistbox>
  <richlistitem>
    <description>A XUL Description!</description>
  </richlistitem>
  <richlistitem>
    <button label="A XUL Button"/>
  </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
<richlistbox>
  <richlistitem>
    <description>A XUL Description!</description>
  </richlistitem>
  <richlistitem>
    <button label="A XUL Button"/>
  </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
<richlistbox>
  <richlistitem>
    <description>A XUL Description!</description>
  </richlistitem>
  <richlistitem>
    <button label="A XUL Button"/>
  </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
<richlistbox>
  <richlistitem>
    <description>A XUL Description!</description>
  </richlistitem>
  <richlistitem>
    <button label="A XUL Button"/>
  </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
<richlistbox>
  <richlistitem>
    <description>A XUL Description!</description>
  </richlistitem>
  <richlistitem>
    <button label="A XUL Button"/>
  </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
<richlistbox>
  <richlistitem>
    <description>A XUL Description!</description>
  </richlistitem>
  <richlistitem>
    <button label="A XUL Button"/>
  </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
<richlistbox>
  <richlistitem>
    <description>A XUL Description!</description>
  </richlistitem>
  <richlistitem>
    <button label="A XUL Button"/>
  </richlistitem>
</richlistbox>
</richlistbox>

</window>
```

Comment: Your first link was the same as one I linked to as well, but your example `richlistbox` helped me figure out why those suggestions didn't help in the first place. I needed to set `listheader` as the container for `treecol` items (works with `listheader` items as well), not `listhead` (which is weird, since [`listhead` is officially advertised as container for `listheader` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/listhead)). The multiple `richlistbox` elements (one for each `richlistitem`) were redundant though. Anyway: thank you for demonstrating a working example!

Comment: Cool man :) Thx for posting about the discrepancy about `richlistbox` i hear its a real finicky thing.