# How can I display XML treeview in a XUL interface?

Tags: xml, dom, treeview, load, xul

I'm currently new to JavaScript and I have to load and display a graphical tree view of an XML file selected by the user in a XUL interface. I need some help in loading the XML file and create its tree,

I have searched a lot but I didn't find anything, I am using `nsIFilePicker` to choose the file in a function that returns the file path but I can't load the XML using DOM parser, and this is the function that reads the file:

```
function loadXML(xmlFile)
        {
        xmlDoc.async="false";
        xmlDoc.onreadystatechange=verify;
        xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
        xmlObj=xmlDoc.documentElement;
    }
```

Comment: I accidentally posted this as solution to your binding thing: Copy paste the solution from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310666/how-do-i-get-a-richlistbox-with-a-fixed-listhead/25321743#25321743

Be sure to read the article here about tips and tricks on it: http://mike.kaply.com/2011/08/05/richlistbox-tricks-for-your-add-on/